# Difference between .load and load event with .bind or .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Intialy i was working with Jquery version 1.9 then below code worked as expected, the alert is shown after complete iframe load.

`$("iframe["iframe1"]").load( function () {alert("Hello"});`

But After **updating to version 3.1**, alert is shown right after iframe is loaded, I mean complete page is not loaded in the iframe  but alert is shown.

Now if I change the function then it is working fine.

`$("iframe["iframe1"]").on("load", function () {alert("Hello"});`

Can anyone help me to know , what changes introduce in new jQuery.

Comment: for me it always works using `.load`

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` method removed starting from version 3 as it conflicted with ajax `.load()`.
instead you can use `.on("load", fn)` as you did